# data frame remove duplicate values within a cell

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I want to remove double values within a cell of column `DTC` for all rows of my dataframe. So in other words i want to remove the double DTCs.
I added a picture for better understanding.

This is the last code part:

```
trans_sequence <- transactions %>%
  group_by(FIN, repdate) %>%
  summarize(
    SIZE = n(),
    DTC = paste(as.character(DTC), collapse = ';')
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Try `sapply(strsplit(trans_sequence$DTC, ';'), function(i)paste(unique(i), collapse = ';'))`

Comment: Try `transactions %>% group_by(FIN, repdate) %>% summarize(SIZE = n(), DTC = paste(unique(as.character(DTC)), collapse = ';') )`

Comment: Many thanks to both of you!!!!